# Using SQL to find the highest energy consumption from given dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Find the date with the highest total energy consumption from the Meta/Facebook data centers. Output the date along with the total energy consumption across all data centers

These are the 3 given datasets

```
fb_eu_energy
date    consumption
2020-01-01  400
2020-01-02  350
2020-01-03  500
2020-01-04  500
2020-01-07  600
```

```
fb_asia_energy
2020-01-01  400
2020-01-02  400
2020-01-04  675
2020-01-05  1200
2020-01-06  750
2020-01-07  400
```

```
fb_na_energy
date    consumption
2020-01-01  250
2020-01-02  375
2020-01-03  600
2020-01-06  500
2020-01-07  250
```

my solution

```
select date, sum(consumption) as total_consumption
from (select * from fb_eu_energy
union all
select * from fb_asia_energy
union all
select * from fb_na_energy
) as output
Group by output.date
order by total_consumption desc
limit 2
```

I have this current solution, but I feel as if using limit 2 is cheating a bit, and wouldn't work for other datasets. Any solution to fixing this issue by using the max function without having to change my answer greatly?

Comment: Please don't link to external resources, everything required for your question should be in the question, espeically as this requires a login / account.

Comment: Why is it `limit 2`? If you want the one date with the highest energy consumption, shouldn't this be `limit 1`? Or are you talking about ties? Do you happen to know that the maximum energy consumption occured twice?

Comment: Hi Michael, could you update your answer to show what your desired result should look like given the data you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Since PostgreSQL 13 you can use the standard SQL clause `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to get the day(s) with the maximum engery consumption:

```
select date, sum(consumption) as total_consumption
from 
(
  select * from fb_eu_energy
  union all
  select * from fb_asia_energy
  union all
  select * from fb_na_energy
) as output
group by output.date
order by total_consumption desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the dense_rank() function:

```
with cte as
(
select date, sum(consumption) as total, 
      dense_rank() over (order by sum(consumption) desc) as rn 
   from
        (select * from fb_eu_energy  
        union all 
        select * from fb_asia_energy 
        union all 
        select * from fb_na_energy) as src
        group by date
        )
select date, total from cte where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select date, C
From (
Select  date,  SUM(consumption)C
From(
select date, consumption from fb_eu_energy
Union All
select date, consumption from fb_asia_energy
Union All
select date, consumption from fb_na_energy
)T  Group By Date 
) t1
where t1.c=(Select  top 1  SUM(consumption)C
            From(
            select date, consumption from fb_eu_energy
            Union All
            select date, consumption from fb_asia_energy
            Union All
            select date, consumption from fb_na_energy
            )T  Group By Date 
            Order By SUM(consumption) desc)
```

Comment: Please don't write code-only answers. Instead, explain how your answer solves the problem.  In this case, especially tell us why you have added this answer one and a half years after the request was posted and got answered. I don't think that PostgreSQL has a `TOP` keyword, by the way. And querying the same tables twice is not necessary either, as you can see from the other answers.